# I want to increase the circle size to radius 200 and then decrease it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

So, Here I am trying to make a circle w radius 1 and increase it to 200, then I want it to get smaller back to 1 and loop this.

I know that `g_radius ++` and then `g_radius --` are creating an effect as if it has stopped but couldn't figure out the solution.

This is what I've tried so far. I can either increase it or decrease.

```
<html>
<canvas width="800" height="600" id="myCanvas"> </canvas>
<script>
    var g_canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var g_context = g_canvas.getContext("2d");


    var g_radius = 10 ;

    function f_drawCircle()
    {
        g_context.fillStyle = "blue" ;
        g_context.beginPath();
        g_context.arc(400,300,g_radius,0,2*Math.PI) ;
        g_context.fill();
    }

    function f_clearCanvas()
    {
        g_context.clearRect(0,0,g_canvas.width,g_canvas.height);
        g_context.strokeRect(0,0,g_canvas.width,g_canvas.height);
    }

    function f_varySize()
    {
        g_radius ++ ;
        if(g_radius > 200)
            {
                g_radius -- ;
            }
    }

    function f_loop()
    {
        f_varySize();
        f_clearCanvas();
        f_drawCircle();
    }

    setInterval(f_loop,10);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable for the direction of the size change, and then add its value to `g_radius`. Like so:

```
var dir = 1;

function f_varySize() {
    if (g_radius > 200) {
        dir = -1;
    }
    if (g_radius < 2) {
        dir = 1;
    }
    g_radius += dir;    
}
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/p2y3cq7h/).

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly, what i was looking for :)